# Apk do Ionic não funciona. Tela branca

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic, apk, build

Bom dia, criei uma aplicação no Ionic, ela funciona perfeitamente, quando uso

```
ionic serve
```

O ionic consegue gerar a Build sem nenhum erro, porém após a instalação da apk aparece somente o header e em seguida uma tela branca. alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente há alguma dependência do seu aplicativo que não está sendo carregada e assim gerando um erro e parando o carregamento correto do app.

Se o seu aplicativo realiza requisições ajax, é possível que ele esteja capturando uma resposta 404 quando tenta executar tais requisições. Este problema é solucionado instalando o [cordova-whitelist-plugin](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist).

Recomendo que você liste os plugins do cordova instalado em sua aplicação digitando no terminal: `cordova plugin list` ou `ionic plugin list`. A maioria dos plugins cordova devem ser registrados no app.js para poderem ser carregados pelo ionic.

Por último, há a opção de você simular seu aplicativo em um aparelho android ou iOS e utilizar um monitoramento para verificar o log do erro.

Se seu dispositivo for android basta plugar um dispositivo android no USB e rodar o comando `monitor` que fica dentro da pasta do [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html).

Se seu dispositivo for iOS basta utilizar o [xCode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/ActivityMonitorInstrument/ActivityMonitorInstrument.html).

Answer (score 0):

Tenha certeza de que voce tem o plugin instalado:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

npm install --save @ionic-native/splash-screen
```

Apos isso , Dentro de *config.xml* coloque essa linha

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

No meu caso essa solução fez efeito ([Creditos](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/splash-screen-white/129476/)).